# Excel XML why does my drag and drop xml element only select a header?

Tags: excel, xml

I'm using Excel 2013 and it has, in the developer tab, an XML import and export function.

I followed instructions [here](https://spreadsheeto.com/xml/#marking) (and at least 3 other pages I found show the same technique)

Supposedly when I drag an `XML element` from my `XML Map` to a header in an Excel table, the whole column is supposed to be highlighted (much like when creating a table in Excel) so the data can be exported

But on my app it only highlights the header and when exporting, it exports only one entry.

My XML schema is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <entry>
        <one>1</one>
        <two>2</two>
    </entry>
</data-set>
```

And my excel chart is literally two columns with a header each and a few rows of arbitrary data

Any ideas on why it's not selecting the whole column of data?

**Update**

I just discovered by adding a second entry to my XML Schema it works fine. Does anyone have the reason/logic behind this? I guess an xml pattern can't be created with only one entry?

Answer (score 1):

I think it considers it a single value only row if there is only one. I had this same problem about 30 minutes ago. Good luck to you!